# Is there a Python module that can automatically detect the type of distribution and extrapolate it?

Tags: distributions, python

I need to evaluate the significance of many values against their respective control distributions, some of which are not normal. For extreme cases, where the value is higher or lower than any value in the control distribution (10^5< N <10^6), I would like to evaluate the one-sided probability to reach at random such a value or a more extreme one by assuming the type of distribution.

Is there a convenient Python module that can detect the type of distribution (including skewness) to evaluate the significance of the value of interest?

For this specific example, I would also have other possibilities to find out the underling type of distribution, but I am curious if a module/software like this exists. However, perhaps the concept of such a module intrinsically violates sound statistical reason.

Comment: I think you're correct at the end. The short answer is no because the question is meaningless.  To make it meaningful, you have to (a) posit a definite family of possible distributions and (b) describe the sense in which you mean "significance of the value of interest."  Although there are modules for "automatic fitting" of distributions to data, they are worth no more than the amount of effort you put into understanding them and controlling them properly.

Comment: Ok I get it. My first intuition was that this is impossible or not meaningful as it might require the evaluation of infinite possible distributions, but this thought was counterbalanced by the fact that infinite series may also have a definable finite sum. In the same manner, the probability of certain distributions to occur in nature might also exponentially decrease so that finite tries might be sufficient.

Comment: So, should I delete the question?